# How force that all connections to my Apache use TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2?

Tags: apache2, ssl, openssl, tls, mod-ssl

I tested on Ubuntu 12.04 (apache 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4 and openssl 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.10) and Ubuntu 13.04 (apache 2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1 and openssl 1.0.1c-4ubuntu8.1).

[here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol) explain how to do so, but I have the following problems:

When try to use:

> SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1

I got the following error:

> [error] No SSL protocols available [hint: SSLProtocol]

when try to use:

> SSLProtocol TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2

I got the following error:

> [error] No SSL protocols available [hint: SSLProtocol]

Th funny thing is that when I use:

> SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -TLSv1

apache don't complain and [this test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) reported that my server not support SSLv2 and TLSv1.0, but yes SSLv3, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2.

Any explanation to that odd behavior? maybe the test tool is broken?

How can I enable just TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2?

Comment: I believe you have `mod_ssl` activated, right?

Comment: Yes, the last example works, **apache don't complain and...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting *SSLCipherSuite* with just ciphers that are just supported in *TLSv1.2* bypass the Apache 2.2 limitation of parse *TLSv1.1* string to limited TLS to version over 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

> How force that all connections to my Apache use TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2?

You might not be able to enable them. The Ubuntu Security team disables TLS 1.2. I believe they disabled TLS 1.1 in the past. They do it for interoperability reasons.

I believe you have three choices.

First, do nothing and use Ubuntu 12's version of OpenSSL. I believe TLS 1.1 is now supported, but you still won't have TLS 1.2.

Second, build and maintain your own [PPA](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/ppa/). There are some instructions for doing so at [Override Distro Package with Custom Package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395280/override-distro-package-with-custom-package) For completeness, there are no existing [Personal Package Archives for Ubuntu and OpenSSL](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=openssl) that offer the full protocols.

Third is upgrade to a later version of Ubuntu, like Ubuntu 14. I'm trying to determine if Ubuntu 14 enables them all at the moment. See [Ubuntu 14, OpenSSL, and TLS Protocols?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440139/ubuntu-14-openssl-and-tls-protocols).