# Which TLS protocols are enabled in Ubuntu 14.04's OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, tls

This is a follow up to [Override Distro Package with Custom Package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395280/override-distro-package-with-custom-package).

Does anyone know if Ubuntu 14.04's OpenSSL enables all TLS protocols (TLS1.0, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2)? Or does it have protocols disabled (TLS1.1 and TLS1.2) like past versions?

Related: how does one even check for this sort of thing?

**Edit**: This is not a bug report question; nor is it a developer question. You guys are taking the "Close as Bug Report" much too far.

Comment: IMO it depends on the specific client (browser, email, etc.), not the OS.

Comment: Thanks Braiam. Ubuntu will disable them. The clients and server have no choice. See, for example, [OpenSSL downlevel version is 1.0.0, and does not support TLS 1.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1256576).

Comment: [I think upstream fixed the problems](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2802&user=guest&pass=guest), I wasn't able to reproduce the issue in Debian Testing, which uses OpenSSL 1.0.1f, so I think that Ubuntu will just import that. If you want to verify just download a copy of Ubuntu 14.04 and test it.

Comment: Thanks Braiam. So I'm clear, what cipher is negotiated with this command: `openssl s_client -connect mail.google.com:443 -servername mail.google.com -tls1_2 -no_comp`? It should be one of the `ECDHE-ECDSA` ciphers like `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`.

Comment: for me `New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256` in Debian.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. The `ECDHE-ECDSA` ciphers are only available in TLS 1.2 (and above, whenever that comes).

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason this is closed is because 14.04 hasn't been released yet, although I think since all the freezes have happened and you have an answer we can reopen it. @Braiam Please post an answer if you can.

Comment: @Seth no, the reason is because it's a bug. Trusty doesn't have imported the patch. OP needs to ask for a Feature Freeze exception as described in the wiki page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FreezeExceptionProcess#FeatureFreeze_for_bugfix-only_updates if he wants the bug fixed for Trusty before final release.

Comment: @Braiam No, the OP asked *if* it had the feature. Nothing to do with a bug.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS \n \l

$ apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ openssl ciphers -v 'TLSv1.2' | head -4
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
```

Answer (score 5):

I would like to summarize the answer by @andrewsomething...

Short answer TLSv1.2.

Specifically on your system use the command:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v TLSv1
```

You can replace v1 with v1.[012] as needed to see details.  Note you will want to use TLSv1 and TLSv1.2  (1.0 and 1.1 are disabled by default).

Answer (score 4):

```
openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
```

Should print what is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [changelog](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.txt), TLS 1.1 was last disabled by a bug fixed in version 1.0.1b (26 Apr 2012). Since then, TLS support was never disabled by default. However, they can be disabled.

To find out whether a server has any of the SSL protocols disabled, you can use:

```
nmap --script +ssl-enum-ciphers example.com
```

This will give you a return like this one:

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-11-06 12:00 UTC
...
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   SSLv3: 
|     ciphers: 
...
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
...
|   TLSv1.1: 
|     ciphers: 
...
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
...
|_  least strength: strong

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 22.15 seconds
```

When a protocol is not supported it is, usually, not present in the list.